# Trouble exporting component variables

Tags: reactjs, components

Here is to code from the component to get a suggestion/autocomplete for a weather app.  The App just needs longitude and latitude to use to load the weather API.  I just can't work out how to get the data from this component (taken from a NPM lib):

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { StandaloneSearchBox, useJsApiLoader } from "@react-google-maps/api";


const libraries = ['places'];
const PlaceComponent = () => {
const inputRef = useRef();

const { isLoaded, loadError } = useJsApiLoader({
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_GOOGLE_KEY,
    libraries
});

const handlePlaceChanged = () => { 
    const [ place ] = inputRef.current.getPlaces();
    if(place) { 
        console.log(place.formatted_address)
        console.log(place.geometry.location.lat())
        console.log(place.geometry.location.lng())
    } 
    
    
  }

 return (
    isLoaded
    &&
    <StandaloneSearchBox
        onLoad={ref => inputRef.current = ref}
        onPlacesChanged={handlePlaceChanged}
    >
        <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            placeholder="Enter Location"
        />
    </StandaloneSearchBox>
  );
 };

export default PlaceComponent;
```

Tried putting them into the export default at the bottom, changing it to a named component and everything else I could think of.  I'm new to React so really struggling

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just attempt to grab some specific data from a component, as the component's primary job is to display the UI.

You CAN however let the parent component/Context API (or whatever the component that runs the primary logic) get the value of the state from the child component by passing in a function and store the values you get from the child inside a `state`.

Here's an example code with comments on the important part.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { StandaloneSearchBox, useJsApiLoader } from '@react-google-maps/api'

const libraries = ['places']
const PlaceComponent = ({ setSomeStorage }) => {
    const inputRef = useRef()

    const { isLoaded, loadError } = useJsApiLoader({
        googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_GOOGLE_KEY,
        libraries,
    })

    const handlePlaceChanged = () => {
        const [place] = inputRef.current.getPlaces()
        if (place) {
            // pass the value to parent component state
            setSomeStorage({
                address: place.formatted_address,
                lat: place.geometry.location.lat(),
                lng: place.geometry.location.lng(),
            })
        }
    }
    return (
        isLoaded && (
            <StandaloneSearchBox onLoad={(ref) => (inputRef.current = ref)} onPlacesChanged={handlePlaceChanged}>
                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter Location" />
            </StandaloneSearchBox>
        )
    )
}

export default PlaceComponent
```

and the parent component

```
const SomeParentComopnent = () => {
    const [someStorage, setSomeStorage] = useState()
    return <PlaceComponent setSomeStorage={setSomeStorage} /> // Pass the `setState` as prop to children component
}
```

Notice the props that are being passed into your `PlaceComponent`, as well as how to store the value to the parent component in the `SomeParentComopnent`.